Im having trouble bulding a project in Java due to an issue with the classpath being outdated
I am using an older branch of a repository that I am trying to build and make modifications to. When I run the command to build it I get this error:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.

Could not find com.burgstaller:okhttp-digest:1.10.
Searched in the following locations:
- https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/burgstaller/okhttp-digest/1.10/okhttp-digest-1.10.pom

Since this is an older version of the project this makes sense and I wanted to replace the link with a newer one. The problem Im having is that although I was able to locate the new link: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.burgstaller/okhttp-digest/1.10
I have no idea how to update the build.gradle file so that it uses it. This is a pretty large repository already so the file is pretty big. I tried adding the link to a couple different dependencies section and it still didnt quite work.
I searched the entire project for any mention of the file so I could update the link but I couldn't quite find anything.
Thank you!
I tried updating the repositories {} and dependencies {} sections of the build.gradle file. I was expecting it to overwrite.
I looked for the link so I could manually replace it. I was expecting to find it, but I didn't.

The URL (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.burgstaller/okhttp-digest/1.10) have Note: this artifact is located at Mulesoft repository (https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/) , Have you added https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/ to the repositories {} settings?
